# Versiones de Visual Studio y de .NET Framework compatibles con SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

me gustaría saber cuales versiones de Visual Studio y de .NET Framework tengo que utilizar para para la conexión a un servidor de datos SQL Server 2000.

He leido que algunas versiones no son compatibles.

Gracias.

Comment: Hay una respuesta que aplica a tu pregunta en http://stackoverflow.com/a/31337150/2026740

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo tienes que hacer la conexión a la base de datos.
[.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Puedes usar un archivo App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="default" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBPrisma;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Hacer referencias a

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

No creo que tengas problemas para conectarte a SQL 2000

```
internal class Conexion
{
    public static SqlConnection Conectar(string cnStr)
    {
        try
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            cn.Open();
            return cn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error de conexión", ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Este es un ejemplo, espero te sirva de ayuda.